# Work around for non-evil JS pop-ups.

Tags: javascript, facebook, hover, share

I have a regular Facebook share links on a site I'm working on.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 'facebook-share-dialog', 'width=626,height=436,top=367,left=150'); return false;">Share on Facebook</a>
```

As well as fire off this link onclick, I have written some JS so it will fire off after a two second hover (sounds silly, but there is method to this).

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/s54Sp/).

This all works, but since JS pop-ups are pretty annoying, Chrome blocks it by default. The obvious workaround would be to open this in an iframe, but Facebook blocks it's content in iframes.

Does anyone know of another way of opening a Facebook link after a two second hover?

Comment: If I leave my mouse over a link for two seconds and a new browser window appears loading content I didn't ask for, I'd call it an evil popup, not a non-evil one. I will close the page never never return. Just FYI. There's a **reason** pop-up blockers only allow pop-ups when the user has taken a positive action.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Okay cool. It's good to get another perspective. I was going for the same sort of effect that's on Dustin Curtis' site for giving Kudos - http://dcurt.is. But I definitely see your point. Thanks for the comment.